# How to save the Firebase Authentication credential?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want user to login only once in the system, any users who have already signed up or logged in into the system should directly navigate to the dashboard of the android app.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't need to try it manually because Firebase stores automatically your login credentials(with your sign in Session) when you sign in with your Google account.

when your 1st activity starts you can check it in
[How Re-authenticate a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`

[read firebase auth Persistence documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically persists the user credentials when they sign in, and tries to restore the user's sign-in session when the app restarts. You can read the user from `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` when your first activity start, and use that value to determine where to navigate to.